# Show forms from php with jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a php file that has 3 forms inside and some insert queries and i separate them with if(isset()) based on what variable comes from $_POST. I want to make the forms appear for example on the center of the page and when the user presses submit the form fades out and the next one from the isset appears. How can i do that?

For example this is the first form

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['date'])): ?>
      <?php if (!isset($_GET['id'])):?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">

          Date :
          <input type="text" name="date" id="date"> </br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <script>
          $("#date").datepicker();
        </script>
        <?php endif;?>
          <?php endif;?>
```

And then if the user presses submit there is an if(isset()) with an insert query.

After the insert query there is another form

```
 <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])): ?>

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?><?php echo " ?id=" . $_GET['id'] . " &date=" . $_GET['date'] . " &seats=" . $_GET['seats']; ?>" method="post">

                  Ώρα :
                  <input type="text" name="time">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit">
                </form>
                <?php endif;?>
```

So what i want is to display them on the center of my page but i dont have to open another page every time i press submit and they will fadeout (or something similar) and display the next form.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could do this with css. Not sure I understand your question though.

- display all 3 forms on the page at once -> no isset stuff, I don't get what that is there for
- hide the ones you don't want the user to see with a class ".hide"
- submit the forms with jquery, as you don't want the page to reload. after submitting, hide the one you just sumbmitted by setting its class to hide and removing hide from the next form

```css
form{
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
form.hide{
    opacity:0;
}
```